# what is the actual difference between Recycling/Standard of VirtualizationMode property in VirtualizingStackPanel?

Tags: wpf, virtualizingstackpanel

What is actually happening in VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode = Recycling/Standard.?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When `VirtualizationMode` is set to `Recycling`, the `VirtualizingStackPanel` will reuse item containers instead of having to create a new one. 
If we start out with this

```
------------------------- 
| Container 1  | Data 1 |  
-------------------------  
| Container 2  | Data 2 |  
-------------------------  
| Container 3  | Data 3 |
```

And scroll one position down, so Data 1 is scrolled out of view and Data 4 is scrolled into view then Recyling will take the item container for Data 1 and reuse it for Data 4.

```
------------------------- 
| Container 2  | Data 2 |  
-------------------------  
| Container 3  | Data 3 |  
-------------------------  
| Container 1  | Data 4 |
```

I've had some problems with this when using attached properties for the Item container, e.g Green background if I have entered edit mode for Container 1. Scrolling down and Data 4 will also have Green background since the Attached Property was still set.

When `VirtualizationMode` is set to `Standard`, the `VirtualizingStackPanel` will create and discard item containers instead of reusing them.

Comment: How did you resolved the issue with "repetition"? I have the same problem right now when using TextBlock's Behavior in item template. Strange.

Comment: I resolved it using a view model and binding the property. so every row item has a different view model.

Comment: I don't know if the converter would have worked in this case. So the attached property value is set based on the binding data via value converter.