# ListBox is virtual by default?

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a WPF ListBox with some user cards inside.
When one of those user cards is created (in the ideal case, when the current user receives it's friend list from the network), it makes a network request for a user's information.
When I scroll in the ListBox , wait a few seconds, and scroll back, the user cards have their default state.
Upon debugging, I noticed they are unloaded and recreated.

How can I stop the ListBox from virtualizing the items like this?

---

Code:

```
            <ListBox x:Name="friend_list" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="data:User">
                        <stuff:UserCard UserID="{Binding Path=UserID}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: Also yes, the ListBox is virtual by default, and you should not disable UI virtualization.

Comment: There aren't going to be many items in there anyway. Also, the users of this app will surely have powerful computers. A few kilobytes (or even megabytes) of RAM is nothing to them.

Comment: I don't understand. I see the ListBox, and the ItemTemplate, but I don't know where it is getting its items from.

Comment: Having users with good machines is no reason to implement crappy applications, because of developers doing that there are lots of WPF haters

Comment: Try setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode` to `Recycling`.

Comment: @Joulukuusi. Bad idea. There should be a ViewModel to retain the data instead, and leave UI Virtualization alone, which improves application performance.

Comment: @HighCore, I don't see how this is a bad idea. This basically instructs the container to keep already rendered items in memory, which is not disabling the virtualization.

Comment: @Joulukuusi, so if you scroll the scrollbar down to the to the bottom, and the list has 100000 items, you will keep the 100000 items in memory. Nice.

Comment: @HighCore The items are added programatically. I might switch to a resource later. And there will NEVER be more than 250. Server limitation. @ Joulukuusi I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: @Joulukuusi Erm... Doing that makes the items move around when scrolling, and they sometimes mix their data... I think I'll have to approach this problem from another angle. I'll try caching the user data instead.

Comment: If you post a minimal working example, we'll try to give you concrete answers instead of guessing. @HighCore, I think you completely misunderstand point of that mode. For a short explanation, please, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/4301534/577167

Comment: see : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724593/why-setting-scrollviewer-cancontentscroll-to-false-disable-virtualization

Comment: Just FYI if the point was lost in discussion: UI virtualization != data virtualization. Each has a different impact on performance. WPF only gives UI virtualization for free, which you can turn off; just know what it really affects when you do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set [`VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.isvirtualizing.aspx) to false on the `ListBox` or set a normal [`StackPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx) as the [`ListBox.ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx).