# How to remove rerendering during Windows UWP ScrollIntoView

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, scroll, uwp

When I use ScrollIntoView for my listview, The page goes blank for a moment and then rerenders, how can I make this more smooth?

Here is my current code:

```
<ListView Name="MessageList" Margin="0,82,0,45"
                  SelectionMode="None"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ItemClick="FileMessage_Click"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MsgDataTemplateSelector}"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind messages}" >

         <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>
         </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

</ListView>
```

And in the code-behind I have this each time a new message is added to the observable collection that feeds into the listview:

```
MessageList?.ScrollIntoView(MessageList.Items[MessageList.Items.Count -1]);
```

Comment: Are you using virtualization on something?

Comment: I haven't added any virtualization, is that automatic anywhere?

Comment: yes, it's automatic.

Comment: How do I turn it off?

Comment: Attached property `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` or at least that's a way, UWP not sure, haven't gotten to play with it enough yet. Worse case scenario just override the `ListView.ItemsPanel`

Comment: Like the second part of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371810/wpf-listview-virtualization-how-to-disable-listview-virtualization) should do. Keep in mind the potential performance hit though if you're loading tons of stuff in there.

Comment: For some reason I don't have a VirtualizationMode property of VirtualizingStackPanel as is shown in that answer, is this an old way to do it?

Comment: That attached property may be a WPF only thing, but changing the ItemsPanel in the second example should port right over to UWP fine.

Comment: Will that work if I'm using a data template selector?

Comment: When I do that, it doesn't automatically scroll to the bottom anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't reproduced your problem completely. On my PC, this problem only occurs at the first time I add item to `ListView`. `ListView` use [ItemsStackPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn298795(v=win.10).aspx?appid=dev14idef1&l=en-us&k=k(windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemsstackpanel)%3bk(vs.xamleditor)%3bk(targetframeworkmoniker-.netcore,version%3dv5.0)&rd=true) as its default panel, which supports UI Virtualization. After changing the default panel to StackPanel which has no support for UI Virtualization, the problem doesn't appear.

You can change the `ItemsPanel` of `ListView` like below:

```
<ListView Name="MessageList" Margin="0,82,0,45"
              SelectionMode="None"
              Height="300"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind messages}" >

            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

</ListView>
```

**Update:** To scroll to the last Item, you need to set the height of ListView and call [ListView.UpdateLayout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.updatelayout.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) before `ScrollIntoView`:

```
 MessageList.UpdateLayout();
 MessageList.ScrollIntoView(MessageList.Items[MessageList.Items.Count - 1]);
```

Comment: This doesn't scroll me to the bottom automatically, thats the problem

Comment: I am also using a data template selector for 5 different data templates, does that effect it?

Comment: You need to set the height of ListView and call Update before `ScrollIntoView`. Please see my Update.

Comment: That solved most of the problem but now it scrolls to show the one message immediately before the most recent message. Why doesn't it scroll all the way down?

Comment: I think it is possibly by design. If there are 10000 or more items. Scrolling all the way down would keep user waiting.