# Document belongs to another FlowDocumentScrollViewer already exception when using scrollbar

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ListView of FlowDocuments:

```
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Document="{Binding Message}"                                                       
                                                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Margin="-10,0,0,0"
                                                      VerticalContentAlignment="Top"></FlowDocumentScrollViewer>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

And whenever I use the **scrollbar** that gets shown after a certain amount of items in the listview to scroll back up, an **External Code Exception** gets thrown:

I clicked "Show External Code" to reveal the details.

[image: Exception]

Comment: Try without virtualization: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23371959/1136211

Comment: Also use a ListBox instead of ListView when you only set the ItemTemplate, and not the View property.

Comment: @Clemens My god, that fixes it. What does that do?