# How to disable groupedlist i.e. SemanticZoom+ListView virtualization in WP8.1 WinRT?

Tags: listview, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I tried the following (as suggested here [ListBox is virtual by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326506/listbox-is-virtual-by-default)):

```
  <ListView.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

This did disable the virtualization but the sticky group headers no longer stick and are not clickable.

The second method below (as suggested here [WPF ListView virtualization. How to disable ListView virtualization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371810/wpf-listview-virtualization-how-to-disable-listview-virtualization)) I do not know how to do in WP8.1WinRt; I cannot find this anywhere:

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing = "Standard"
```

So **how can I disable groupedlist** i.e. SemanticZoom+ListView **virtualization** in WP8.1 WinRT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can bear losing the sticky group headers, then the first approach of using a plain `StackPanel` can be extended to recover the semantic zooming. Modify your `HeaderTemplate` to include a handler for e.g. the `Tapped` or `Clicked` event (depending on your control). In this handler you can do:

```
SemanticZoom.IsZoomedInViewActive = false;
```

to activate the jumplist.

You might also have to fix the scrolling that `SemanticZoom` does when returning to the zoomed in view. See [this post](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-gridview-performance-problems-on-windows-rt-tablets/) for some example code.