# Scroll Viewer vertical scroll position

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, scrollviewer, flipview, scroll-position

I have a problem with setting Scroll Viewer vertical scroll position (C#, Windows Store App).

I have a FlipView, which contains 2 to 5 items. Item is my own user control - Grid in Scroll Viewer.
I need to change scroll position to all FlipView items, when current selected FlipView item scroll position has been changed.

In my user control I use event:

```
private void MyScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _myPage.ChangeFlipViewItemsScrollPosition(MyScrollViewer.VerticalOffset);
}
```

In my page I use method:

```
public void ChangeFlipViewItemsScrollPosition(double verticalOffset)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MyFlipView.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        MyUserControl item = MyFlipView.Items[i] as MyUserControl;
        if (item != null && i != MyFlipView.SelectedIndex)
        {
            item.MyScrollViewer.ChangeView(null, verticalOffset, null);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that:

For example, I have 5 items in FlipView.

When FlipView selected index is:

0 then it changes scroll position to items with index: 1 and 2;

1 then it changes scroll position to items with index: 0 and 2;

2 then it changes scroll position to items with index: 0, 1 and 3;

3 then it changes scroll position to items with index: 2 and 4;

4 then it changes scroll position to item with index: 3;

I have no idea, why it is happening. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What is your ItemsPanel in FlipView? Can this be somehow related to virtualization? Put a breakpoint on the first line inside the `if` and see what type the other items are.

Comment: @Márton Molnár Tnx you for a comment...I just realized that i need to delete the virtualization from Stack panel and then all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `FlipView` has an item container which is using *virtualization* to enhance performance. That means that the controls for items that aren't currently visible may be discarded or reused.

I didn't find any Windows Store app-specific documentation, but the behavior is probably very similar to that of WPF, explained [here](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/497#.VVBbH_mqpBc). See some more code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13330630/318508).

You can turn it off by either setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing` to `false` on your `FlipView`, or replacing the container with a plain `StackPanel` (or any other non-virtualizing container).

Comment: Thank you, I just replaced it with plain StackPanel and it works.