# C# DataGrid cell colour seems random wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cell

I've written some code to try and change the color of a DataGrid cell based on the length of the value inside the cell. However it appears to work correctly when it loads in the first few rows however when i scroll down past the rows in view it seems to randomly change colour.

My XML behind this is:

```
  <DataGrid  Grid.Row="2" Name="DataGridView1" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="LightGray" RowBackground="#BDBDBF" AlternatingRowBackground="#E3E3E5" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}">
```

My 'CellStyle' Resource is

```
 <local:ValueToBrushConverter x:Key="ValueToBrushConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource ValueToBrushConverter}}" />
    </Style>
```

And finally my ValueToBrushConverter is:

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataGridCell dgc = (DataGridCell)value;
        System.Data.DataRowView rowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)dgc.DataContext;
        var input = rowView.Row.ItemArray[dgc.Column.DisplayIndex];
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\DM Data\Inputs.txt",true);
        sw.WriteLine(input + "      " + input.ToString().Length);
        sw.Close();
        sw.Dispose();
        if (input.ToString().Length < 32)
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LimeGreen);
        else if (input.ToString().Length >= 32)
            return (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF1616"));
        else
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
```

Note the streamwriter is merely for my testing to see what the values are returning.

As said the code works initially but after stops working, this gif shows what i mean

https://gyazo.com/099873b8738887bddaf418c3b45129e3

You can see some values that should not be highlighted become highlighted and visa versa

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the UI virtualization, i.e. the item containers are reused as you scroll through the items.

You can disable this by setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode` attached property to `Standard`, at the potential cost of some scrolling performance:

```
<DataGrid ... VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
```

[what is the actual difference between Recycling/Standard of VirtualizationMode property in VirtualizingStackPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300964/what-is-the-actual-difference-between-recycling-standard-of-virtualizationmode-p)

A better option would be to use a specific `CellStyle` for each column that binds to the actual source property of the item, e.g.:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Name, 
                                    Converter={StaticResource ValueToBrushConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Hello, I'm getting the error 'InvalidOperationException: Cannot change the VirtualizationMode attached property on an ItemsControl after Measure is called on the ItemsHost panel.'